# Android emulator is not responding while running appium and conf.js from protractor

Tags: android, android-emulator, jasmine, protractor, appium

Emulator is started but it is not responding when i run my protractor scripts.
Here is my appium log

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4713 --avd Android --device-ready-timeout 5 --session-override --platform-name Android --platform-version 20 --automation-name Appium --device-name "emulator-5558" --log-no-color
>   info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4713
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","port":4713,"sessionOverride":true,"logNoColors":true,"avd":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5558","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"20","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"5.0.1","browserName":"chrome","device":"android","appium-version":"1.4.16.1","deviceName":"emulator-5558","fullReset":"True","count":1}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
>   warn: Converting cap fullReset from string to boolean. This might cause unexpected behavior.
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : device, appium-version, count
>   info: Set mode: Proxying straight through to Chromedriver
>   info: [debug] Looks like we want chrome on android
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 88548d59-21c7-4236-b62f-59385df19066
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? false
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Launching Emulator with AVD Android, launchTimeout 120000ms and readyTimeout 120000ms
>   info: [debug] Checking whether emulator is present
>   info: [debug] Using emulator from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   info: [debug] Trying to find Android emulator
>   info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: [debug] 1 emulator(s) connected
>   info: [debug] Sending telnet command to device: avd name
>   info: [debug] Getting running emulator port
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device created
>   info: [debug] Socket connection to device ready
>   info: [debug] Telnet command got response: AVD_Nexus5
>   info: [debug] Emulator Android not running
>   Killed Node Server.
>   Appium server process ended

Here my conf.js file :

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4713/wd/hub',
    specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
    // directConnect: true,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '5.0.1',
//    'browserName': 'chrome'
        browserName: 'chrome',
        device: 'android',
        'appium-version': '1.4.16.1',
       // udid:'currentDeviceUDID',
        deviceName : 'emulator-5554',
        'fullReset': 'True'
    },

    // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.
  //  baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:4713',
  baseUrl: 'http://choko.org/',


    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
};
```

[image: Here is the emulator that is launched but not responding]

Comment: I'm having the same problem... If Appium starts the Emulator (setting the "avd" capability) I get this "Emulator Nexus5 not running", even after Emulator is up and running. If I don't use the "avd" capability and start the Emulator myself before running the test, everything works. And I can't find an answer anywhere on how to fix this... Did you have any progress?

Comment: @AlexTondello I have same problems with you but I don't know why. On my old PC (window 8) it working fine. now change to window 10. It happen this issue. I must uncheck checkbox launch avd

Comment: @AlexTondello : I didn't find an answer because i moved to Mac

Comment: @GreyWolf :  me too i'm using windows 10 while having this issue